# Can't get id from simple model in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5.1

I have a model defined in Laravel 5.1. For some reason, I can't seem to get the id from it:

```
Psy Shell v0.5.2 (PHP 5.6.13-0+deb8u1 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> $survey = \App\Survey::where('id',54)->get();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#682
     all: [
       App\Survey {#693
         id: 54,
         created_at: "2015-10-12 03:18:32",
         updated_at: "2015-10-12 03:18:32",
         location_id: 0,
       },
     ],
   }
>>> echo $survey->id;
PHP error:  Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id on line 1
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the 'get' method for retrieving your recrods. But in fact the 'get' method returns a collection of models.

So in order to get your id you need to use for example a foreach statement to loop over the collection.

But you could also use another option that will give you just a single model instance.

For example:

```
$survey = \App\Survey::where('id',54)->first();
$survey = \App\Survey::find(54);
```

Both will return a single model instance.

So after this you can just use:

```
echo $survey->id;
```

To access your id.

See this link for more information about this topic: [Retrieving Single Models / Aggregates](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access the id on collection and it will throw an error. Try modifying the query to

```
$survey = \App\Survey::where('id',54)->first();
```

by replacing `get()` by `first()` and it will work fine.

Or you can use `find()` to get the record by primary key `$survey = \App\Survey::find(54);`